# How to write a filter to replace text instead of hiding the element

Tags: filter, adblock

I'm using Ublock origin to change how my pages look and hide annoyances.

I want to hide text in an element instead of filtering the object. It's a span object with an unique class that has a specific height. It sits at he top of the page and when hiding the element, a whole chunk of the page moves up, while other objects don't, making the page look bad.
Is there a way to write a filter in ublock origin that replaces the text inside the object with a space?

```
<span class="unique-id">text to hide</span>
```

Resources:

[ublock static filter wiki](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax)
[ABP filter guide](https://help.eyeo.com/en/adblockplus/how-to-write-filters)

Comment: You probably have to do this with [scriptlet injection](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax#scriptlet-injection)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

`yourWebsite.com##.unique-id:style(display: none !important)`

Comment: This hides the element, no?

Comment: Well, yes. But it demonstrates that you can change the style of the element to how you want, without actually having it stripped from the html. A better choice may be visibility: hidden which should reserve the item's space in the layout, but not actually show it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to hide text in an element instead of filtering the object.

> `<span class="unique-id">text to hide</span>`

It is possible to do this using the replace-node-text.js scriptlet in uBlock Origin.  The source code for the scriptlet is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gorhill/uBlock/master/assets/resources/scriptlets.js).

replace-node-text.js can be used to replace the text content of any element with different text.  By replacing the original text with empty text, it can also remove text as you are seeking to do.

So, to remove the text content from the span tag in your example HTML, use one of the following uBlock rules:

```
[website hostname]##+js(replace-node-text, #text, text to hide, "")
```

OR

```
[website hostname]##+js(replace-node-text, #text, text to hide)
```

OR

```
[website hostname]##+js(rpnt, #text, text to hide, "")
```

OR

```
[website hostname]##+js(rpnt, #text, text to hide)
```

"rpnt" is the abbreviated name for the scriptlet.

There are a couple of caveats in doing this:
First, because this scriptlet has the "requiresTrust" set to "true", you can only use this scriptlet in rules that you place in the text box of uBlock Origin's "My filters" tab in its settings.  You cannot place your rules with this scriptlet in a custom list that you load under "Filter list".

Second, my example rule above will replace all instances of "text to hide" with "" where the text is a text node.  It should be possible to make the filter target more specific, but as of now, I have only been able to get "text" to work as the selector for this.  The rules which use this scriptlet in the current version of the official "uBlock filters – Ads" list, are all targeted at the "script" selector with no rules for the text selector.

Comment: The remove-node-text scriptlet is also now available in uBlock Origin, and it can be used all text from a DOM node without the "requiresTrust: restriction.  BUT, it removes ALL of the text from a node, not just selective text.

The syntax for the command is as follows:

[website hostname]##+js(remove-node-text, #text, <text used to select node>)

The text in the third parameter is used to identify the text node, but ALL of the text in that node will be removed not just the text specified in the third parameter.